# Какие паттерны проектирования мобильных приложений используются сейчас?

Tags: android, ios, шаблоны-проектирования, react-native

Занимаюсь мобильной разработкой на react native. Стоит ли использовать MVC/MVP если есть redux? Есть мнение что не стоит использовать redux в мобильной разрабокте, так ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну все зависит от проекта. Тут нет какого-то правила или серебряной пули.

Наверное самые распространенные это:

- **MVP** - он появился одним из первых после **MVC** и неплохо вписывается в концепцию Android. Много больших проектов которые начинали свое развитие после 10-ых годов используют его и по сей день.
- **MVVM** - это уже так сказать улучшеная версия MVP где Presenter (в случае MVVM это обычно ViewModel) ничего не знает о существование View. Этот подход активно поддерживается и пропагандируется Google. Именно поэтому вы видим такие библиотеки как: [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding), [Live Data](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) и [View Model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel). Хотя в этом подходе очень многие хейтят Data Binding, но этот подход можно использовать и без него.
- **MVI** - модно, стильно, молодежно. Полностью реактивный подход, в котором все модели иммутабельны. Более сложен для вхождения. Ребята из Badoo написали на него неплохой фреймворк. Вот [тут](https://habr.com/ru/company/badoo/blog/429728/) есть неплохая серия статей.

Есть и другие, но как говорилось выше, все зависит от команды и проекта.